# Is it common to use "A" and "B" to represent something during talking?

Tags: meaning-in-context

E.g. I would like to say "Lets call (someone from some department) A, and (someone from some department) B. A and B are....".

Is it common to do it in English?

Comment: In my experience, yes!

Comment: That thing began at the end of the 15th century and became popular in the 16th, in the Age of Enlightenment with the work of Descartes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard substitute names used more often, plain names like "Sally" and "Jim", but "A" and "B" would not sound strange at all. However, you may want to call them "person A" and "person B", at least the first time you mention each.